# basic calculation is returning NaN in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to calculate the line and cart total of this cart.
[image]
I have an array from local storage that supplies data to this html

```
  var arrayLength = cartarry.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

 var id = cartarry[i].id;

  var name = cartarry[i].name;
  var price = cartarry[i].price.replace('$',"")
  var quantity = cartarry[i].quantity;


 var itemcontainer = document.getElementById('myContent');


  var itemcard = `
                  <div class="product" id="${id}">

                    <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-title">Dingo Dog Bones</div>
                    <p class="product-description"> ${name}</p>
                   </div>
             <div class="product-price" id='productprice'>${price}</div>
                   <div class="product-quantity">
                  <input type="number" id='productquantity' value=${quantity} min="1">
                  </div>
                  <div class="product-removal">
                 <button class="remove-product">
                                              Remove
                                            </button>
                                          </div>
                <div class="product-line-price" id='productlineprice' >25.98</div>
                </div>
                            `
                    ;
                    itemcontainer.innerHTML += itemcard;
                    calculatetotal()            
}
```

this is my update quantity function

```
     /* Update quantity */
function updateQuantity(quantityInput)
{
 /* Calculate line price */

  var price = parseInt($('.product-price').text());
  var quantity = parseInt($(quantityInput).val());
  var linePrice = price * quantity;
  console.log(price,quantity)
  /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */
  $('.product-line-price').each(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
  $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
  recalculateCart();
  $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
  });
 });  
}
```

The output is NaN for all line price as shown in the picture. what do you think I'm doing wrongly and how can I fix it?

Comment: could it be that `$('.product-price').text()` still contains the currency symbol which needs to be removed before converting to an integer? (also, are prices really always integers?)

Comment: Try fixing duplication of id values `productprice`, `productquantity` and `productlineprice` first. These are being assigned to inputs for each cart item, but having multiple elements with the same id is invalid.

Comment: it's not just id values. It's the jQuery selectors for both id's and Css class. Arrays are being returned